# C# object reference

Tags: c#, object, reference

i don't know what you call it, but how would i change fields / use methods from an object, with the object i want to call with, a field?

Comment: Has anyone really been far even as decided to use even go want to do look more like?

Comment: Can you re-phrase? It's really hard to understand what you're looking for help with.

Comment: @Mark: What for don't go how deciding when/where to feel like with not looking more like how to be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
object1.object2.property
```

You can access object2 as a property of object1, and then access object2's properties just like normal

Comment: Thanks, this is what i wanted.

Sorry i couldn't rephrase well

Comment: +1 for expert deciphering skills